# Is it possible to have a warning when using a uninitialized variable

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2015

I don't know if it's a Javascript effect but I find myself trying to use uninitialized variable quite often when programming on the client side.

The C# compiler prevents you from doings things like that. Since TypeScript seems to have the contextual information necessary to do this kind of check I was wondering if there is a way to have warnings when trying to use a unitialized variable in the context of a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use strict mode in JS 'use strict' and declare your variables with the var keyword then I believe you will get warnings when your local scoped variables are undefined.

Also Visual Studio now gives you warnings for this I believe.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode